# Child Dialog - SetWindowTextA or SendMessageA crashes program - MFC

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc

**ERROR: afxwin2.inl line 165**

My app is a dialog box with a few edit boxes. Once I click the button to evaluate the information entered I want to open a child dialog to display the results. I tried overloading DoModal() like this:

```
//in the child dialog
//.h    
CResultsDlg::CResultsDlg(CParentDlg *parent); 
virtual INT_PTR DoModal(float bmi); 

//.cpp    
CResultsDlg::CResultsDlg(CParentDlg *parent) : CDialogEx(CResultsDlg::IDD), _parent(parent)
{   //initializations  }

INT_PTR CResultsDlg::DoModal(float bmi)
{
    m_sBMI.Format("%f", bmi);
    m_hBMI.SetWindowTextA(m_sBMI); //crashes !!!!!!!!!! 
    m_hBMI.SendMessageA(WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)"15.11"); //crashes !!!!!!!! 

//  OnInitDialog(); //because this wasn't getting called at all
    return CDialogEx::DoModal();
}

BOOL CResultsDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();
//  __super::OnInitDialog(); //no difference...

m_hBMI.SetWindowTextA("10.3"); //crashes !!!

return true;  // return TRUE unless you set the focus to a control
}


//in the parent dialog 
//.cpp
void CParentDlg::OnBnClickedCalculate()
{
    CResultsDlg childResultsDlg = this;
    childResultsDlg.DoModal(15.7);
}
```

m_hBMI is a handle to a static text control. I tested an edit box but it still crashed. 
I understand that it probably has something to do with the controls not being created yet but I tried every way I know.

Using breakpoints, I confirmed that OnInitDialog does not get called at all unless I put it in the overloaded DoModal function. SetWindowText/SendMessage still crashes in OnInitDialog with the same ASSERT error.

If I remove all SetWindowText/SendMessage then the child window does come up modal like it should but the 'result' static text control is the same as the text I set it to in the dialog editor properties pane.

Thanks !!!!!

*MORE DETAILS*-----------

```
void CResultsDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)    // DDX/DDV support
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_BMI, m_fBMI);
    DDV_MinMaxFloat(pDX, m_fBMI, 0, 100);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_BMI, m_hBMI);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual sequence when you start a dialog is:

- You call CDialog::DoModal.
- The dialog window gets created.
- The child controls of the dialog get created.
- OnInitDialog gets called.
- CDialog::OnInitDialog calls DoDataExchange.
- You have a DDX_Control call in your DoDataExchange method to map the child control to a member variable.

Notice that the member variables only get initialized at the end of that sequence. You're trying to use them way before, so you get a crash.

Store the value you need for initialization in a member variable and take care of it in DoDataExchange.

Comment: So "m_sBMI.Format("%f", bmi);" is OK just don't try to set it in DoModal ? I'm not sure how to 'take care of it in DoDataExchange'. Even if I add a button in the child and try to call m_hBMI.SetWindowText("15") when clicked it still crashes and this is long after the child and its controls should have been created. My empty child's OnInitDialog doens't get called either tested with breakpoints.

Comment: @Soran actually formatting a string that isn't a control should be OK. And you shouldn't even need the SetWindowText since that's what DDX_Text does internally.

Comment: I'm still pretty confused...I put breakpoints in each child function and the only one that's getting called is the child's constructor and BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP (not OnInitDialog nor DoDataExchange).........