# Child's DoDataExchange is never called in child dialog ? - MFC

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, winapi, mfc

I simply want to open a child dialog and have it print a result from the parent dialog in one of the child's static text controls. Using breakpoints I noticed that both DoDataExchange and my overloaded OnInitDialog are never called in the child so the static text control crashes any time i try to print something to it. The child dialog does display itself fine otherwise.

What could be the problem ?

```
//in parent.cpp
CResultsDlg childResultsDlg = this;
childResultsDlg.DoModal(15.7); //overloaded to pass value to a child member var
```

---

more information from my previous post
[Child Dialog - SetWindowTextA or SendMessageA crashes program - MFC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22262781/child-dialog-setwindowtexta-or-sendmessagea-crashes-program-mfc)

Comment: What is the meaning of "CResultsDlg childResultsDlg = this"? It does not appear to make sense to assign one dialog to another.

Comment: I did it to enable messages to be sent from the child back to the parent. I don't know another way...

Comment: If I take the 'this' off the child crashes on the return of the overloaded DoModal which is "return CDialogEx::DoModal();"

Comment: You have several errors and misunderstandings, but we can't see the code. Reporting that it "crashes" is insufficient information.

Comment: I provided a link containing several details to another question of mine with the same underlying problem...

Comment: If my question is too convoluted, I would be more than happy with a link to a tutorial/example that does what I ask so I can emulate and learn it. ie: An example of a parent dialog passing a value to a child dialog and having that child send it to a text control - because I am yet to see one. Thanks !

Comment: Check if you have called `CDialog::OnInitDialog()` inside your `CResultDialog::OnInitDialog()`. This call is necessary to call your `DoDataExchange`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the basics of MFC are covered in the SCRIBBLE tutorial.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f35t8fts(v=vs.90).aspx

An example of passing data into a dialog and displaying that data in dialog controls is provided in the tutorial with the `CPenWidthsDlg`.